# TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my server.js file and api.js file. I am getting an error in the sort function in which I intend to search the js objects according to their attributes.The event Schema has the attributes as name, location, price, rating. I tried to sort it according to their prices.

**server.js**

```
var express= require('express');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var config=require('./config');
var app= express();
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
//var User=require('./database/user')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db',function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("connected!");
    }
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true })); //if false then parse only strings
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));//log all the requests to the console
var api=require('./app/routes/api')(app,express);
app.use('/api',api);
app.get('*',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});   // * means any route

app.listen(config.port,function(err){
    if(err){enter code here
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("The server is running");
    }
});
module.exports = router;
```

**api.js**

```
var User = require('../models/user');
var Event = require('../models/event');
var config = require('../../config');
var secret = config.secretKey;

module.exports = function (app, express) {
    var api = express.Router();
    app.use()

    api.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
        var user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
        });
        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json({
                message: 'User created!'
            });
        });

    });

    api.get('/users', function (req, res) {
        User.find({}, function (err, users) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json(users);
        });
    });

    api.post('/eventfeed', function (req, res) {
        var event = new Event({
            name: req.body.name,
            location: req.body.location,
            description: req.body.description,
            price: req.body.price,
            rating: req.body.rating
        });

        event.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json({
                message: 'Event created!'
            });
        });
    });

    // utility function for sorting an array by a key in alpha order
    api.get('/sortby_price', function (err) {
        if (err) return err;
            // utility function for sorting an array by a key in parsed numeric order
        else {
            function sortArrayNum(arr, key) {
                arr.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return parseInt(a[key], 10) - parseInt(b[key], 10);
                });
            }

            var dicts = EventSchema.saved;
            for (var i = 0; i < dicts.length; i++) {
                var terms = dicts[i].terms;
                sortArrayNum(terms, "price");
            }
        }
        return api;
    });
}
```

This is my error. I am making a webpage for the first time using this. Kindly help me what does this error tells.

> TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions
>      at EventEmitter.use (c:\Users\MY APY\WebstormProjects\Main\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:209:11)
>      at module.exports (c:\Users\MY LAPY\WebstormProjects\Main\app\routes\api.js:10:9)
>      at Object. (c:\Users\MY LAPY\WebstormProjects\Main\server.js:20:36)
>      at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>      at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
>      at startup (node.js:129:16)
>      at node.js:814:3

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496100/cannot-app-usemulter-requires-middleware-function-error?

Answer (score 86):

I had this problem when I left out

```
module.exports = router;
```

in my Routes.js.We need to export all the routes.

In my server.js, I had

```
var mainRoutes = require('./Routes.js')
app.use(mainRoutes)
```

So check your 'app/routes/api' file to see if it has proper export.

Answer (score 13):

Middleware is a function with access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next middleware in the application’s request-response cycle, commonly denoted by a variable named next.

Middleware can:

- Execute any code.
- Make changes to the request and the response objects.
- End the request-response cycle.
- Call the next middleware in the stack.

If the current middleware does not end the request-response cycle, it must call next() to pass control to the next middleware, otherwise the request will be left hanging.

In api.js line number 10 is invalid

```
app.use()
```

app.use must have a function with 3 params

```
// a middleware with no mount path; gets executed for every request to the app
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   console.log('Time:', Date.now());
   next();
});
```

if you want only few selected paths to use this middleware you can do something like this

```
// a middleware mounted on /user/:id; will be executed for any type of HTTP request to /user/:id
app.use('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
   console.log('Request Type:', req.method);
   next();
});

// a route and its handler function (middleware system) which handles GET requests to /user/:id
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
   res.send('USER');
});
```

Take a look at the expressjs documents it is pretty good.
http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: `app.use` doesn't need to have 3 parameters. It only needs to have the parameters you're interested in using.. You can easily omit the `next` if you're not interested in passing downstream. OP's biggest problem, in addition to his faulty `app.use()`, is also that his external module does not return a middleware, but this is mounted in his main file.

Comment: thanks for the information I'm equally new to node.js.

Comment: for me worked changing ``app.use`` to ``àpp.get``

Answer (score 13):

You need to export your router in bottom of route file

like this `module.exports = router;`

and use in app.js file

```
const mainRoutes = require('./Routes.js')
app.use(mainRoutes)
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

`app.use` requires that you pass it a function which is then used as middleware. You have two instances where you do not do this which will cause this error; both of which are in `api.js`.

`api.js:10` `app.use()`

You do not pass a function to `.use()`, and so this will cause an error. This is the error you're seeing in your post.

However, you will get another error:

```
var api=require('./app/routes/api')(app,express);
app.use('/api',api);
```

This section attempts to mount the return value of your `./app/routes/api` module function as a middleware. However, we can see inside your code that you do not actually return a value from the function in api.js; you instead return the router from inside a route handler..

```
// utility function for sorting an array by a key in alpha order
api.get('/sortby_price', function (err) {
    if (err) return err;
        // utility function for sorting an array by a key in parsed numeric order
    else {
        function sortArrayNum(arr, key) {
            arr.sort(function (a, b) {
                return parseInt(a[key], 10) - parseInt(b[key], 10);
            });
        }

        var dicts = EventSchema.saved;
        for (var i = 0; i < dicts.length; i++) {
            var terms = dicts[i].terms;
            sortArrayNum(terms, "price");
        }
    }
    return api; // <- this will be returned inside the app.get call
});
```

You should instead move this out of the handler and to the end of your function.

The total amended code will look like this:

```
module.exports = function (app, express) {
    var api = express.Router();
    ..omitted for brevity..

    // utility function for sorting an array by a key in alpha order
    api.get('/sortby_price', function (err) {
        if (err) return err;
            // utility function for sorting an array by a key in parsed numeric order
        else {
            function sortArrayNum(arr, key) {
                arr.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return parseInt(a[key], 10) - parseInt(b[key], 10);
                });
            }

            var dicts = EventSchema.saved;
            for (var i = 0; i < dicts.length; i++) {
                var terms = dicts[i].terms;
                sortArrayNum(terms, "price");
            }
        }
    });
    return api;
}
```

Comment: I removed those errors. It was my fault. I didn't see that but when I am opening /api/sortby_price it is not responding and when I debugged it, it is not even going into the function. What might be the error?

Comment: @bob, I rolled back this edit because the modification you made to the first code block would not have worked with OP's code as-is. However, the second edit you made, where you removed 'app' from the module.exports was fine. Please feel free to add that back in.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue recently. I exported the module as follows:

```
module.exports = { router };
```

Removing the curly braces fixed the error for me.

```
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error happened due to writing

```
app.use('/v1/tutorials');
```

instead of

```
 app.use('/v1/tutorials',router);
```

Answer (score 0):

My original function was `app.use('/api/cars'. carRoutes)`, where I was running into the error:

> TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions'

As I had a full stop between the in-between 'api/cars' and 'carRoutes'.

I changed to a comma and I stopped running into the problem.