# NodeJs Multer error

Tags: node.js, multer

I'm getting the follow error while trying to retrieve uploaded files.
I've searched the net and all I found is that people are injecting the result from multer() as midleware but all I got is errors ...

```
/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458
  throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a
        ^
TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object
at Function.use (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:219:21)
at Array.forEach (native)
at EventEmitter.use (/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:216:7)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app.js:40:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

Here is the code of that part of the app

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var mul = multer({limits : {fileSize : 1000000, files : 10}});
var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var server = require('http');
app.use('/files', mul, files);
function files (req, res) {
  console.log(req.files, req.file);
}
server = server.createServer(app);
server.listen(process.env.PORT || port);
```

Comment: please refer here:
[multer error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496100/cannot-app-usemulter-requires-middleware-function-error)

Comment: Please refer here:
[multer error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496100/cannot-app-usemulter-requires-middleware-function-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code you have for configuring routes and multer seems a bit wrong. Thats's how it's described to be [here](http://lollyrock.com/articles/express4-file-upload/). Second parameter(s) in `app.use` should be **function or functions** [app.use docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) while `mul` in your code is an *Object*, result of your configuration factory call earlier here : `var mul = multer({limits : {fileSize : 1000000, files : 10}});`

```
//other stuff    
var mul = multer({limits : {fileSize : 1000000, files : 10}});

app.use('/files', [mul, files]);

function files (req, res) {
  console.log(req.files, req.file);
}
//other stuff
```

**UPD**

did you try like this, according to docs on module page?

```
var mul = multer({ dest: 'your_uploads_path/' });
app.use('/files', mul.array(), files); //or other option
```

other options are here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#multer-opts

**UPD2**

[According to docs](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#limits) `multer` indeed returns object, that should be consumed by `busboy`, so you need it to be required and configured as well - https://github.com/mscdex/busboy#busboy-methods

Comment: what error you get in that case?, when you have 'app.use('/files', [mul, files]);'

Comment: The same that express expects function but gets an Object

Comment: did you tryed use example from official multer page - https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer ? check updated answer

Comment: It doesn't throw an error but the request doesn't get captured eighter. if you mean the one with multer().array()

Comment: yes - one of the options single, array or fields. Did you also tried changing app.use to app.post ?

Comment: with app.post and var mul = multer({limits : {fileSize : 1000000, files : 10}}); still throws.

Comment: with app.post and var mul = multer({limits : {fileSize : 1000000, files : 10}}); and app.post(...,mul,...);  still throws but with mul.any() works well. but your ans helped me so I'm going to close the q

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that works, thanks to @shershen

```
//other stuff    
var mul = multer({limits : {fileSize : 1000000, files : 10}});
app.use('/files', mul.any(), files);
function files (req, res) {
console.log(req.files, req.file);
}
//other stuff
```